# How to stop Internal link redirection looping in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

In my prestashop site with in a jquery script i have written an if condition.If the "if" condition is true,I want to redirect my site to [login page](http://example.com/sg/authentication?back=my-account) .Condition is false means it should redirect to the [contact us page](http://example.com/sg/contact-us%20page).But this internal link redirection is keep on redirecting based upon condition. Instead of the prestashop site url if i have provided an   [external url](https://stackoverflow.com/) means redirection happening only once properly.How to overcome this multiple redirection looping problem with this internal site links?

Note: Just for example i have expalined with login page and contact page.It may be any of the prestashop page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var code=firstshop; 
if( code == "firstshop" )
{ 
   window.location="http://localhost/jewellery/shop1/";
}

else
{
  window.location="http://localhost/jewellery/shop2/";
}
//
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information on your "condition" or post some code. You probably need to check that the visitor is not already on the page that is desired

```
if (condition && !isLoginPage) {

} else if (!condition && !isContactUsPage) {

}
```

Comment: I have updated my code.kindly check.just for example i have told us login page and contact page.But i want to redirect the site to any of the prestshop link from my stie.@ teambob